# Get direction from degrees

Tags: javascript, math

I built a small compass project that is able to calculate the devices heading. SO what I got is a function that returns a value between **0° and 360°** for the current heading.

What I like to get is a matching value for the current heading direction from an array like this: (`["North", "North-East", "East", "South-East", "South", "South-West", "West", "North-West"]`)

[image: img]

(keep in mind: North = 0° / 359°)

---

However I got no idea how to get a result like this & this few lines below are all that I got so far but it doesn't seems working:

```
var directions = ["North", "North-East", "East", "South-East", "South", "South-West", "West", "North-West"]

function getDirection(heading) {
   var index = Math.round((heading/8)/5,625)
   return directions[index]
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: And what are the possible values for `heading`?

Comment: `Math.round((heading/8)/5,625)` makes no sense

Comment: `returns a value between 0° and 360°` like I've mentioned :9 @dfsq

Comment: So `heading` is a value between 0 and 360?

Comment: I don't have time to run tests, but I think it is just
`var index = Math.floor((heading / 22.5) + 0.5) % 16`

Comment: @JaneDeverly Ah crap, I was thinking of it being `["N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE", "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW"]` so the 16 should be 8.

Comment: Ahh, then youre completely right. Good solution though! `Thanks :)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This solution should take all possible scenarios in consideration:

```
var index = Math.round(((angle %= 360) < 0 ? angle + 360 : angle) / 45) % 8;
```

```js
function getDirection(angle) {
    var directions = ['North', 'North-East', 'East', 'South-East', 'South', 'South-West', 'West', 'North-West'];
    var index = Math.round(((angle %= 360) < 0 ? angle + 360 : angle) / 45) % 8;
    return directions[index];
}

console.log( getDirection(0) );
console.log( getDirection(45) );
console.log( getDirection(180) );
console.log( getDirection(99) );
console.log( getDirection(275) );
console.log( getDirection(-120) );
console.log( getDirection(587) );
```

Comment: Nice solution but please edit the directions like this: `["North", "North-West", "West", "South-West", "South", "South-East", "East", "North-East"]`. Exact the solution I was looking for.

Comment: @JaneDeverly Yep, thanks. I've just copied the directions from your question `:)` Now fixed.

Comment: Won't this method return inverted values as for example for angle 90, it should return east but the function says west.