# Calculate degrees from a 2D heading vector

Tags: c#, vector, linear-algebra, angle, direction

I am trying to add sprites to a game I am currently working on. I have sprites for `north`, `south`, `west` & `east` directions. I've already found [how to get a direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750528/get-direction-from-degrees) from degrees, the problem is that I can't seem to calculate the right amount of degrees (**0° to 360°**) from a normalized velocity vector, called `heading`. Check figure 1 below for my `velocity` vector, my `heading` vector is a normalized clone of this vector.

What I want to achieve is that:

- A property `degrees`: returns the right amount of degrees, based on a current heading/velocity vector.
- A method receiving `degrees` as parameter, which in turn can return a direction which I can use when drawing my sprite.

[image: Velocity vector]

**Figure 1:** my 2D velocity vector

My code for calculating the heading vector:

```
Vector2D heading = Velocity.Clone.Normalize();
```

I am also not sure if using a `heading` vector is necessary, so if it's possible or preferred to use the `velocity` vector, please tell me and include this in your answer.

Comment: This might be what you're after: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17530240/2363967

Comment: Can you provide some sample values and answers?